# Build fails after adding geofence plugin

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Trying to add https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence to a project under Visual Studio. Plugin adds okay from the UI on the config.xml. However, when then trying to build, the build fails with an error 'Error 2   Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Arguments to path.join must be strings'. The plugin shows up in the config XML when I view the code, and the plugin has been added to the plugin directory. Removing the plugin allows build to proceed fine. Build server is my Mac running the remote agent, no issues except this.

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geofence':TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings (TaskId:11)
1>      at path.js:360:15 (TaskId:11)
1>      at Array.filter (native) (TaskId:11)
1>      at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36) (TaskId:11)
1>      at module.exports (/Users/anthonyhumphreys/remote-builds/builds/34458/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/hooks/add_swift_support.js:11:37) (TaskId:11)
1>      at runScriptViaModuleLoader (/Users/anthonyhumphreys/remote-builds/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:151:18) (TaskId:11)
1>      at runScript (/Users/anthonyhumphreys/remote-builds/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:129:16) (TaskId:11)
1>      at /Users/anthonyhumphreys/remote-builds/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20 (TaskId:11)
1>      at _fulfilled (/Users/anthonyhumphreys/remote-builds/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54) (TaskId:11)
1>      at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/anthonyhumphreys/remote-builds/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30) (TaskId:11)
1>      at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/anthonyhumphreys/remote-builds/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13) (TaskId:11)
```

This is the entry for the plugin in config.xml

```
<vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geofence" version="0.4.0" />
```

I installed the plugin via the gui in VS2015 RC as I read on a VS blog that there was a bug involving plugins that was resolve in the RC....Any help truly appreciated, thanks folks.

Comment: Did you get same issue with any other plugin? Share the diagnostics build log may show more info. In VS, tools->options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run-> change the MSBuild output to "Diagnostics"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for late follow-up. Edited q to include some more verbose logging.

Comment: I will suggest you clear the cordova cache on your mac and retry the build. If it still fails I will suggest you do a test using command line as mentioned in  http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html .